# Get setting and data using server side datatables jquery plugin 1.9?

Tags: jquery, datatables

i am using  DataTables  plug-in for the jQuery Javascript library. It is a highly flexible tool which will add advanced interaction controls to any HTML table.

For drawing the table on html page i have following jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var columns;
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./viewController",
        data:{ "TableName" : "ViewGridDept",
        "Call" : "gridConfiguration"},
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(coldata){
        //columns=data.aoColumns;
        //var coldata = eval( '('+data+')' );
        alert(coldata.aoColumnsRef);
        employeeTable = $("#EmployeeTable").dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI" : true,
        "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
        "bFilter": true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource" : "./viewController",
        //"aoColumns":coldata.aoColumns ,
        "aoColumnDefs":coldata.aoColumnsRef,
        //"aoColumnDefs":[{"sTitle":"Department Name","mDataProp":"deptName","aTargets":"[1]"},{"sTitle":"Department ID","mDataProp":"deptId","aTargets":"[0]"}],
        "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
            aoData.push( { "name" : "TableName", "value" : "ViewGridDept" },
            { "name" : "Call", "value" : "Data" } );
            $.ajax( {
                    "dataType": 'json', 
                    "type": "POST", 
                    "url": sSource, 
                    "data": aoData, 
                    "success": fnCallback
                    } );}

});
        }
```

});

in this code i send the ajax call to server to get table setting.and after render the table setting second ajax call sent to server for data. i get all my "aoColumnDefs" data from server side in form of json :

```
{"aoColumnsRef":[{"aTargets":[1],"mDataProp":"deptName","sTitle":"Department Name","bVisible":true,"bSearchable":true},{"aTargets":[0],"mDataProp":"deptId","sTitle":"Department Id","bVisible":true,"bSearchable":false}]}
```

My question are :

1) Is this method to load setting and data from server is correct.

2) Is their any other way to get data and table setting from server side .(table setting means columns title,target,searching ,sorting and all related setting to tables)